# How to work on the cited reasons for the refusal of visa?

Tags: canada, student-visa, study, refusal

My visa application for a study permit has been refused yesterday.

They are citing the reason that

1. I won't leave Canada after my stay because of my current employment situation.
2. My plan and progression of study don't make any sense.

I am planning to submit the visa application again.

What points do I need to work on to make sure that I am not refused for the second time?

**FAQs**

> What am I applying for?

I am applying for study permit. I have an acceptance from a canadian university to study CS Masters by thesis program. My target is to get a Ph.D. But, the accptance I have right now, is for a Masters by research program.

> What did I submit along with my visa application?

My financial papers, marriage certificate, ...

I have strong family ties. My wife and daughter are in my country, I supplied my family photo, and I clearly described that I want to get back to my country after my Masters. But, I didn't tell them that I want to do a Ph.D. in Canada. Coz, I thought that may complicate the situation. But, still, they refused me.

> What is my current employment situation?

I left my job because of stress and went to a non-English speaking country for study. I don't have a job and I don't have any plan to do any job anytime soon in the future.

> What is my academic situation?

I came to the country 'X' to (1) escape my then stressful job, (2) to get prepared for a Ph.D.

But, then, I understood that (1) the academia of that country 'X' is tough to suit for me because of the difference in highereducational culture, and language. (2) the higher education of that country 'X' is considered inferior to Canada/North America.

So, my Masters program is half done, and **even if** I can't get to Canada, I don't intend to finish my study here.

Comment: > I left my job because of stress and went to a non-English speaking
> country for study. I don't have a job and I don't have any plan to do
> any job anytime soon in the future Nope nope nope. The correct way of saying is:
I am not satisfied with the field of my current studies/education imparted and hence want to change university.

Comment: I think the first step is to reach, in your own mind, a consistent view of your plans. Do you intend to return home after a master's, or stay in Canada for a PhD? What sort of job do you plan to get, and where will that be? Once you know what you really plan to do, it will be easier to prepare a consistent, believable application.

Comment: @MarkMayo, which questions?

Comment: @anonymous apologies, I misread hers and realised they were more 'thought exercises' than actual questions. Reopening and bumping to top.

Answer (score 2):

> My plan and progression of study don't make any sense.

This is key: regardless of how it was expressed in your first application, you should resolve what you want to study, where, and why. You’re in a Master’s program, halfway through, and you don’t intend to complete the program: you left your own country, was admitted to an institution in another, and are abandoning that pursuit. You admit here (if not in your application either for a visa or university) that you really want a Canadian Ph.D., pretending (as you say) that you would return to your home country after obtain a Master’s.

Academics and entry clearance officers are adept at critical thinking: if what you have shared here is any indication, those reviewing your visa application believe, rightly, that you're not being straightforward. Applying for a Master's program when you're already in one is a bit confusing. Prior to reapplying, you should solidify your academic and career path (and an incomplete Master’s program may not improve your chances of a favorable decision).

> What is my current employment situation?

You’re unemployed, resigned because of stress, enrolled in school out of country, left your family behind, don’t plan to get a job any time soon. You should appreciate that these decisions may not contribute to a successful visa application. How do you support yourself and your family, where are the considerable funds required of applicant who wishes to study in Canada (approximately $24,000)?

> What is my academic situation?

Should the Master’s, you’re pursuing be 'inferior' to that of Canada (or the US), do you wish to have any of that course work be accepted by a program in Canada? Do you plan to begin an entire Master’s program in Canada? Would that make you an attractive candidate to a Canadian university?

I realize all of this may be tough to read but, realistically, you would want address and remedy any significant shortcomings identified in your refusal before reapplication to Canada (or another country and institution).